# How to disable array generation using Podam?

Tags: java, jemos-podam

I need to generate random values in my objects, but I don't need it to generate list of objects.

For example when I have:

```
class MyObject {
  private String name;
  private List<OtherObject> others;
  // setters, getters
}
```

I need to have only `MyObject` with `name` as a result. List of `others` should be empty.

How to achieve it?

EDIT: I can't use any annotations on MyObject since it's a generated object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
As I was looking at the code of the library, I realized, podam wouldn't fill an immutable List. Therefore I made a List manufacturer to create only immutable lists.

```
PodamFactory podamFactory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
podamFactory.getStrategy().addOrReplaceTypeManufacturer(List.class, (strategy, attributeMetadata, genericTypesArgumentsMap) -> Collections.emptyList());
Object object = podamFactory.manufacturePojo(clazz);
```